# How to give a style to all textbox placeholders

Tags: css, css-selectors

I want to pick all text box place holders and give it a generic style.
What i have in mind:

```
      <style>
        .textbox > placeholder
        {
        font-size: 15pt;
         }

      </style>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this trick.

```css
::-webkit-input-placeholder { /* Chrome/Opera/Safari */
  color: pink;
}
::-moz-placeholder { /* Firefox 19+ */
  color: pink;
}
:-ms-input-placeholder { /* IE 10+ */
  color: pink;
}
:-moz-placeholder { /* Firefox 18- */
  color: pink;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="this is the placeholder text"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Cross browser code:

```css
.textbox::-webkit-input-placeholder {
   color: red;
}

.textbox:-moz-placeholder { /* Firefox 18- */
   color: red;  
}

.textbox::-moz-placeholder {  /* Firefox 19+ */
   color: red;  
}

.textbox:-ms-input-placeholder {  
   color: red;  
}
```

```html
<input type="text" class="textbox" placeholder="I am placeholder" style="width: 200px;" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

[Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/priyasingh/jk3hcz4j/)

```
input::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  color: red;
}
```

For more reference **https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/style-placeholder-text/**

Answer (score 0):

Please check this link: 
https://davidwalsh.name/html5-placeholder-css,

example:

```
/* for all */
::-webkit-input-placeholder { color:#f00; }
::-moz-placeholder { color:#f00; } /* firefox 19+ */
:-ms-input-placeholder { color:#f00; } /* ie */
input:-moz-placeholder { color:#f00; }

/* field is id, individual: webkit */
#field2::-webkit-input-placeholder { color:#00f; }
#field3::-webkit-input-placeholder { color:#090; background:lightgreen; text-transform:uppercase; }
#field4::-webkit-input-placeholder { font-style:italic; text-decoration:overline; letter-spacing:3px; color:#999; }

/* individual: mozilla */
#field2::-moz-placeholder { color:#00f; }
#field3::-moz-placeholder { color:#090; background:lightgreen; text-transform:uppercase; }
#field4::-moz-placeholder { font-style:italic; text-decoration:overline; letter-spacing:3p
```